# PHP File Copy() Not working on IIS 6

Tags: php, iis, file-upload

I have the following code that attempts to take a users form input of a file, and upload it to the webserver.

This code does work on a Apache server, however I'm now trying to get the same code working on my Windows IIS 6 web server, which has PHP (Version 5.2.3) installed and working.  I have set the PHP.INI file so that

file_uploads = On

upload_tmp_dir = "C:\Temp"

My form is

```
<form method="POST" action="do_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="img1" size="30">
    <input type="submit" name="BtnUpload" value="Click To Upload Now">
</form>
```

My PHP code to do the upload is

```
$abpath = "C:\MyWebs\Website1\httdocs\images";

@copy($img1, "$abpath/$img1_name") or $log .= "Couldn't copy image 1 to server";

if (file_exists("$abpath/$img1_name")) 
{
  $log .= "File 1 was uploaded";
}
else 
{
  $log .= "File 1 is not an image";
}
```

For some reason when I check the value of $img1 e.g echo $img1; it is empty. Therefore I tried to get the file using $_FILES['img1']['name'].  This worked fine, but still I couldn't upload any files

Any ideas why this is happening.

Comment: Remove the error suppression operator (`@`) and make sure you're displaying all the errors by adding `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script.

Comment: Because `$img1` and `$img1_name` hasn't yet been defined.

Comment: Yes I'm getting Notice: Undefined variable: img1_name.  But why do I get this on IIS but not Apache ?

Comment: Why no errors on Apache, that I couldn't say (probably error reporting is OFF). See [**Marc B's answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19729140/1415724) below, which will give you a better insight. I was going to suggest the same thing, but he beat me to it. @Tommo1977

Comment: Do consult the manual on the [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function for more information. @Tommo1977

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img1']['tmp_name'], "$abpath/$img1_name");
```

Don't `copy()` uploaded files. There are a few edge cases where an uploaded file can be tampered with, which is why move_uploaded_file() exists - it checks for those particular types of tampering.

As well, be **VERY** careful with how you create your filenames when processing the upload. If you directly use ANYTHING provided in $_FILES as part of the destination path/name for the file, you are opening bad security holes on your server, and a malicious user can exploit that to scribble a file anywhere they want on your server.

Comment: In your example above, am I going to be able to access "$abpath/$img1_name" ?

Comment: Probably. it would appear $abpath is inside your document root. But since you don't say what you mean by "access", no way to answer properly.

Comment: Thanks, changing my code to move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img1']['tmp_name'], "$abpath\\".$_FILES['img1']['name']) or $log .= "Couldn't copy image 1 to server"; worked.

Comment: general tip: on windows you can still use `/` as the directory separator in PHP. PHP will auto-convert to backslashes for you, and it saves you having to double-backslash everything. `c:/mywebs/foo/bar` works just fine.